# assertion error using .at & remap without interpolation

Tags: c++, opencv

I was trying to obtain undistorted image without interpolation but i am getting an assertion error. 
Since the remap is providing with one of the interpolation method but i need the image without interpolation, so i have tried the below code but it is giving an error.

```
 Mat R = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_32F)*1;  
 unsigned int width = cf1.cols;
 unsigned int height = cf1.rows; 
 Mat mapx = Mat(height, width, CV_32FC1);
 Mat mapy = Mat(height, width, CV_32FC1);
 initUndistortRectifyMap(Cam1MatrixParam, Cam1Distortion, Cam1MatrixParam, R, imagesize, CV_16SC2, mapx, mapy);

for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
undistorted.at<uchar>(mapy.at<float>(j, i), mapx.at<float>(j, i)) = cf1.at<uchar>(j, i);
}
}
```

> error: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data &&
>   (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] &&
>   (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) <
>   (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211)
>
> > > ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at

can someone help me ?

Comment: You should post the assertion error message, not just say that you have an assertion error.

Comment: Put the information in the original post, not in a comment.